# NyroModal doesn't close correctly

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

Here's sample a code.

```
$(".remove.group").live("click", function (ev) {
    var button = $(ev.currentTarget);
    var action = button.get(0).dataset["action"];
    var method = button.get(0).dataset["method"];
    var modal = $("#remove");
    modal.find(".primaryaction").bind("click", function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: method,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (rawResponse, status, xhr) {
               //some business logic
                $.nmTop().close();
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(arguments);

                var message = "Could not remove group";
                alert(message);
                $.nmTop().close();
            }
        });
    });
    modal.find(".cancelButton").bind("click", function (e) {
        $.nmTop().close();
    });
    $.nmManual("#remove");

    return false;
});
```

I am using [nyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) and jQuery here.

All the click events work fine for the first time. But if I do reopen the modal again and click on either of the buttons nyroModal ends up throwing error:

> this.elts.cont is undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the debug version, I solved this problem by adding a test for the elts existence.

```
       _unreposition: function() {
            if (this.elts.length) {
               this.elts.cont.css('overflow', '');
               var elts = this.elts.all.find('.nmReposition');
               if (elts.length)
                   this.elts.cont.append(elts.removeAttr('style'));
            }
            this._callFilters('afterUnreposition');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness do what @Sparkx did, but then I had one more error which was "TypeError: nm.elts.cont is undefined". To fix this change:

```
hideCont: function(nm, clb) {
  nm.elts.cont.css('overflow', 'hidden').fadeOut(clb);
```

to:

```
hideCont: function(nm, clb) {
  if(nm.elts.cont) nm.elts.cont.css('overflow', 'hidden').fadeOut(clb);
```